# TestCafe Update "local" Chrome in Jenkins

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I am running tests in Jenkins and the tests are running on outdated Chrome 71 and I want to update the chrome it is using. I've tried updating my package.json to current TestCafe but it is still running 71. when I run node_modules/.bin/testcafe --version it just lists firefox, chrome. It seems that since the chrome is in node_modules I should be able to update to latest but I haven't found anything online to show how to do so.

Running locally on my machine chrome is v91. I thought doing an 'npm i' locally and pushing that branch would update but it was not successful.

Jenkins output:

- npm i
- node_modules/.bin/testcafe --version
  1.15.0
- node_modules/.bin/testcafe -e chrome:headless auth-subscriber-signs-in-validates-homepage.js
  Running tests in: Chrome 71.0.3578.98 / Linux 0.0

Comment: So does anyone know where/how to load chrome onto Jenkins where TestCafe can pick it up? I've tried ${JENKINS_HOME} and {WORKSPACE} path but then node modules won't load with npm i. It seems this is the path to chrome google-chrome: /usr/bin/google-chrome.

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe doesn't upgrade or downgrade browsers. It just searches the installed browsers and runs tests in them. You need to inspect the Jenkins job and found the way how browsers are installed for it.